# Outlook 2010 Rules on an IMAP Account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, email-filter, rules

I have an IMAP account set up in Outlook 2010.  This account receives notices from scheduled tasks.  It receives a LOT of messages.

I want to filter the messages that contain error reports into a new folder.  I created a rule in Outlook that looks for specific text in the message.  The problem is that the filter doesn't seem to see the text unless I have already viewed the message.  How can I work around this limitation?

---

**EDIT**

This post was originally for Outlook 2003.  I am now using Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Outlook 2003 I worked around the issue this way:

1. Selected all the messages, right-clicked, and selected option to download the messages
2. Ran "Send / Recieve"
3. Manually ran the Rule

In Outlook 2010 step #1 above no longer exists.  I followed instructions to [force Outlook to download the complete IMAP items](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/force-outlook-2007-to-download-complete-imap-items/) and then all I have to do is step #3.  For some reason the rule doesn't get applied even though I'm telling Outlook to download the complete IMAP item.